How can i get all the followerss of my company through the LinkedIn Api
I have searched for a solution from the LinkedIn API which can return me all the followers of my compaany, i have found that it is getting them through this url in their website:
(https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/graphql?variables=(start:0,count:6,organizationalPage:urn%3Ali%3Afsd_organizationalPage%3A102438999,followerType:MEMBER)&queryId=voyagerOrganizationDashFollowers.ecbb7bbbbad91a62222e6525045e68cd)
and i have also found some solutions which are not covering my case, like :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/organizations/follower-statistics?view=li-lms-2024-04&tabs=http
follower statistics which only returns 'FollowerCountsByparameter'
and an endpoint which returns the total count of followers
I cannot succeed to find a way to fix it, i have thought about selenium script but that is my least wanted option because it will be slow.
